# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger

Tags: java, log4j

I tried to execute a jar from server and I got this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
```

The same jar works good in my local machine.Can any one point me the way to resolve this.

Comment: Log4j jars are in classpath? are you using maven?if you are check if log4j is added to pom.xml

Comment: Yes I am using maven but I am creating a jar by simply exporting it.Let me check

Comment: are you exporting the jar from eclipse? there is an option to package the dependent jars along with resultant jar, make sure that option is selected. also open the jar in winrar or similar and verify if the log4j jar is present inside

Comment: Nope still having the issue.I extracted my jar and I found the log4j jar in it .

Comment: Its resolved now..I exported it as runnable jar with all libs extracted.

Comment: @Abx : Can you tel me how you were you able to make it as runnable jar ? is it through command line or in the code?

Comment: @ravi.zombie I was using eclipse ..It has an option to export as runnable jar..Try using that..